# Design EF Core three entities joining to a single table

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

New to code first approach and EF Core. Stuck with issue of how to implement the solution for 3 entities joining through a common entity.

Here are my entities

```
 public class Activity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }     
        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleActivities{ get; set; 
    }



 public class Application
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleActivities { get; set; }
    }

public class Role
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> ApplicationActivities { get; set; }
    }

 public class RoleApplicationActivity
    {

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }

        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public Application Application { get; set; }

        public int ActivitId { get; set; }
        public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    }
```

I basically want to achieve the following tabular mapping

```
Role    Application Activity
1         1          1
1         1          2
2         1          1
2         2          1
```

Can you please help me if my entity design is correct for this approach?

Here is my code for creation of key for the triple join table.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<RoleApplicationActivity>()
               .HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.ApplicationId, ur.ActivitId });
```

Edit:

Looks like I found answer. I have generated my design in sql server and Scaffold-DbContext to generate the code for me.

Here is the code that it has generated.

```
public partial class Activity
    {
        public Activity()
        {
            RoleApplicationActivity = new HashSet<RoleApplicationActivity>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleApplicationActivity { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Application
    {
        public Application()
        {
            RoleApplicationActivity = new HashSet<RoleApplicationActivity>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleApplicationActivity { get; set; }
    }
 public partial class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            RoleApplicationActivity = new HashSet<RoleApplicationActivity>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleApplicationActivity { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class RoleApplicationActivity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int ActivityId { get; set; }

        public Activity Activity { get; set; }
        public Application Application { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nchar(10)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Application>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nchar(10)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nchar(50)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<RoleApplicationActivity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Activity)
                    .WithMany(p => p.RoleApplicationActivity)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ActivityId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_RoleApplicationActivity_Activity");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Application)
                    .WithMany(p => p.RoleApplicationActivity)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicationId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_RoleApplicationActivity_Application");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.RoleApplicationActivity)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_RoleApplicationActivity_Role");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Your entities look to be wrong.  I don't believe you need to specify the special triple join as well.  EF recognizes all of the tables joins from the code in the classes.  I'll try and rewrite what you have.

Comment: Don't update the **question** with the **answer**. Post it as real **answer** please.